# Unexplained limping

Tags: dogs, health, medicines

My dog is a rescued Labrador/English mastiff cross, so she's big(but not fat) at 35 ish kg and approximately 8.

She has been limping at times which has come and gone. Currently it's quite bad.

She has undergone arthritis treatment which has not worked. Then we tried codeine with metacam and still no improvement.

We then had her go for full body x-ray and still nothing: no arthritis, broken bones, displesia, tumours or any lumps.... absolutely nothing!

This is now to be confirmed by a specialist but we think it will still be nothing.

Does anyone have any ideas? My
Father in law believes it's a sprain?

Edit: it comes and goes: she was really bad (as she is at the moment) a couple of years ago. Then it literally just stopped. This year, in March, she started to have a slight limp, then it went away. She went for a long walk with her dog friends and returned really bad.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean when you say "comes and goes"?  That is potentially helpful information.

Comment: Is it the same leg she limps on? Do you check for pickers in between her pads or cuts when this issues is present? Does this only happen after an activity or does it happen when she is doing normal activities inside the house? Is she laying on hard floors or uneven surfaces?

Comment: All these things have been checked. It historically happens after a long walk and then lasts for month, only this time it's worse. Even surface at home. She has recovered before. She's currently always limping

Comment: Has she been tested for lyme disease? Though usually the lameness switches legs - unsure if this is your case.